# How to pass commas as page items in ORACLE APEX

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to pass a list of numbers separated by commas to use in my SQL query in clause but I found out that you can't pass commmas. Is there a way to do this? I have tried putting backlash and other things to pass, and it still doesn't work. Can I put semicolons instead, and change the semicolons back to commas into commas before the table loads the query using the bind variables? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to split comma-separated values into rows. Here's an example:

```
SQL> select * from dept
  2  where deptno in
  3    (select regexp_substr('&&P1_IN_LIST', '[^,]+', 1, level) deptno
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= regexp_count('&&P1_IN_LIST', ',') + 1
  6    );
Enter value for p1_in_list: 10,30

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        30 SALES          CHICAGO

SQL>
```

The same Apex query would look like

```
select * from dept
where deptno in
  (select regexp_substr(:P1_IN_LIST, '[^,]+', 1, level) deptno
   from dual
   connect by level <= regexp_count(:P1_IN_LIST, ',') + 1
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Except that you can pass commas, it's supported.
https://community.oracle.com/thread/4148695

And if you want to pass a list of numbers, why use commas?
How are you using these numbers?

Describing *what* you're trying to solve instead of how you've attempted to solve it is usually better. And if you're only describing what you've tried, you should at least go into detail, particularly since the solution is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/understanding-url-syntax.htm#HTMDB03019).